# How to get values from textbox and other html elements values into label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi i have a form in my application where user can put their details. My form portion looks like this,

http://jsfiddle.net/2MSXP/

in this when user click on add school hyperlink, i want all values appended into label like,

School:  12th

School Name: St. Xavier's

School Location: Banglore

Class Year: 2010

Branch: Science

This should be appended any no of time when user click on add school hyperlink.

How can i do that using javascript/ jquery?

Comment: Did you try anything? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: actually i dont have any idea how can i do that. :(

Comment: Have you tried an introduction to jQuery [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery)? Any good beginning tutorial will have enough info to help you implement your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in the text boxes can be accessed by `document.getElementById('id').value`

The remaining should be easy for you to figure out.

Here's how you could do it not using JQuery:

```
    <a href="javascript:show()">Add School</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show()
        {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "School Name: " + document.getElementById('sch1').value; 
        }
    </script>
```

Add a `span` or div with the id `result` wherever you want the result to show.
Expand on the code above to display the other fields as well.

have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GQdsD/

`innerHTML` overwrites what was held in the HTML container before. You can do this:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "School Name: " +
document.getElementById('sch1').value + "<br/>Location: " + 
document.getElementById('schloc1').value + "<br/>Year: " + 
document.getElementById('schoolyear').value + "<br/>Branch: " + 
document.getElementById('branch1').value;
```

OR, collect the values in a JS var and then write it to the HTML container:

```
var result = "School Name: " + document.getElementById('sch1').value + 
"<br/>Location: " + document.getElementById('schloc1').value + 
"<br/>Year: " + document.getElementById('schoolyear').value + 
"<br/>Branch: " + document.getElementById('branch1').value;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

To allow multiple adds, change this line in your code:

```
var result = "School: " + document.getElementById('schools').value + "<br/>School Name: " + document.getElementById('sch1').value + "<br/>Location: " + document.getElementById('schloc1').value + "<br/>Year: " + document.getElementById('schoolyear').value + "<br/>Branch: " + document.getElementById('branch1').value; 
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

To this, so it adds the new information to the old information:

```
var result = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML + "<br/>School: " + document.getElementById('schools').value + "<br/>School Name: " + document.getElementById('sch1').value + "<br/>Location: " + document.getElementById('schloc1').value + "<br/>Year: " + document.getElementById('schoolyear').value + "<br/>Branch: " + document.getElementById('branch1').value; 
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: $("#addtolabel").click(function () {
            alert(document.getElementById('schools').value);
            alert(document.getElementById('sch1').value);
            alert(document.getElementById('schloc1').value);
            alert(document.getElementById('schoolyear').value);
            alert(document.getElementById('branch1').value);
        }); By using this i am getting values of all elements but how can i put it into lable?

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer. make a label with the id `result`. The `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML` will find the label with the id `result` and put the values in there.

Comment: @Debugmode: added a jsfiddle link. have a look at it.

Comment: @xbonex : Thanks... I tried this but it showing only last element. function show() {
               document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "School Name: " + document.getElementById('sch1').value;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Location: " + document.getElementById('schloc1').value;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Year: " + document.getElementById('schoolyear').value;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Branch: " + document.getElementById('branch1').value;}

Comment: @xbonex: is there any way to get multiple add of this division. as i am able to get only one school in result div. as per my application requirement user can add multiple school on his profile. how can this possible. and thanks for your valuable support. please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/GQdsD/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can add function to button and get values like...

```
$('.profileupdateBod').click(function(){
    $('#yourContainer').append('<div>School : '+$('select[name=schooldivision]').val()+'</div><div>School Name : '+$('#sch1').val().trim()+'</div>')
})
```

Also check jquery selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

For Select Box:

```
$('#select_box_id option:selected').text();
```

For Text Box:

```
$('#text_box_id').val();
```